# How to display records that are x days old from present date?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my application am allowing the user to enter number of days. based upon users entry i need to display only those records which are x days(User's entry) older from present date.
talltree_master is the name of the table
lastdtems column keeps track of the dates on which last entry was done.
For ex. if user enters number of days as 40. then query should display all the dates(from lastdtems column) which are older then 40 days.

```
string query = "select area_id,row_id,tree_no,talltree_id,block_id,dtlastemas from talltree_master";
query += " where talltree_master.block_id=" + block + " and talltree_master.area_id =" + area + "";
```

Above code till now displays only display above selected fields. I need a code that will display only those records which are x days older from present date.

Today date is retired using

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Comment: SQL Injection allert! Please us [parameterized sql](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) instead.

Comment: lastdtems<DateTime.Now - 40 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add an additional where-clause to your statement

AND dtlastemas <= '2013-09-01'

you could code it like this :

var _dateFrom = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(- NrOfDays);

// your SQL statement 
+ " and dtlastemas <= '" + string.format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", _dateFrom) + "'";

I agree with Soner's comment above, you should avoid SQL-injection by using parameterized SQL.

regards,
Jurjen